# Azure Storage Throws Metadata Error Message on Occasion

Tags: c#, azure, monodevelop, azure-table-storage

When calling an Execute statement on an Azure Table store to get back existing data (to check if data exists before populating data) I receive an error message "The metadata URI 'https://my.azure.table.core.windows.net/$metadata#MyTable/@Element' is not valid for the expected payload kind 'Entry'.

It might be a red-herring, but the table itself has been deleted and re-created a number of times (in development, software has a bit of "if it doesn't exist create" logic); and it seems like sometimes it creates and is happy; sometimes time makes things better.

It does look to work most of the time, but when it fails it fails consistently for sometime (usually resulting in a deletion of the table and re-try)

I've followed the basic examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet so I'm thinking there is just something subtle that I'm not aware of or that I need to clarify to ensure this doesn't happen.

The code I'm using is

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureConnectionString);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(myTableName);
table.CreateIfNotExists();

TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<MyDataEntity>(itemPartitionKey, itemRowKey)
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
{
    TableOperation inserOperation = TableOperation.Insert(loadMyDataItem);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

Again it could be a red-herring, but it seems like if the table doesn't exist then it runs through find and adds that data; but on the second pass (i.e. restart the program) that it fails on the table.Execute with the "metadata URI" error message.

I've attempted to separate out the create as well and put that as a different part of the process (so that I only have the check for existing data and then insert operation), but that doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Update: this is being run through MonoDevelop

Update: it looks like this works if it is the first time through and/or there is no data in the table store (i.e. so that the result is null);  if there is data it looks to fail initially and then after time "come good";  if there is data an I use the ExecuteQuery methods instead of the Execute method it looks to work more consistently.  I'll likely move to ExecuteQuery (maybe just better implemented in MonoDevelop?), but it still feels like I'm doing something incorrectly and could resolve with better code.

Comment: Which line code you get the exception `The metadata URI 'https://my.azure.table.core.windows.net/$metadata#MyTable/@Element' is not valid for the expected payload kind 'Entry'.`?

Comment: I get the exception on the TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why this works and the above method doesn't; but this looks to be a viable workaround if others are having this issue.

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery<MyDataEntity>().Where(
                                                             TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                                                                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, itemPartitionKey),
                                                                TableOperators.And,
                                                                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, itemRowKey)));
var myDataEntities = table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery).ToList();
if (myDataEntities.Count == 0)
{
    TableOperation inserOperation = TableOperation.Insert(loadMyDataItem);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

It seems that it Execute doesn't fail when there is no data in the database, but seems to fail when there is (at least when it has recently been added).  I'm not sure if that is Mono or Azure or some combination that is causing that.

The transition to TableQuery and ExecuteQuery, while more code seems to work thought.